# R replace nested lists' values by the values from another table

Tags: r, list, replace

I have a table with nested lists like this:

```
library(dplyr)
data <- data.frame(id = c(123,124,125,126)) %>%
  mutate(a = list(c("orange", "apple"), c("banana", "melon"), c("kiwi", "melon"), c("apple", "banana")),
         b = list(c("kiwi", "apple"), c("melon", "apple"), c("orange", "melon"), c("apple", "orange")))
```

I want to replace all values in *a* and *b* with the corresponding values from new_values:

```
new_values <- data.frame(fruits = c("orange", "apple", "banana", "kiwi", "melon")) %>% 
  mutate(param = list(c(1,2,3), c(2,3,4), c(4,3,1), c(1,4,2), c(3,4,1)))
```

Comment: So `c("orange", "apple")` will become `list(c(1,2,3), c(2,3,4))`?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a nested `lapply` -

```
data[-1] <- lapply(data[-1], function(y) {
  lapply(y, function(x) new_values$param[match(x, new_values$fruits)])  
})
```

Or in `tidyverse` -

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

data %>% mutate(across(a:b, function(x) 
         map(x, ~new_values$param[match(.x, new_values$fruits)])))
```

Output is a nested list -

```
data$a

#[[1]]
#[[1]][[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3

#[[1]][[2]]
#[1] 2 3 4


#[[2]]
#[[2]][[1]]
#[1] 4 3 1

#[[2]][[2]]
#[1] 3 4 1
#...
#...
```